# Indent members in header

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using the AccessModifierOffset to indent the Access Modifiers. But what I now would like to have that the members are indeted one step more.

So that this

[image]

becomes this

[image]

How to achieve this?

These are my clang format settings:

```
---
AccessModifierOffset: '0'
IndentWidth: '4'
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: 'false'
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
TabWidth: '4'
UseTab: Always
ColumnLimit: 0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported by clang-format, but there is an open feature request [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19056).

It says:

> Daniel Jasper:
>
> > The bar for such a flag is:
> >
> > 1. A large project using it.
> > 2. An open style guide precisely describing the style.
> >
> > Do these apply?
>
> Teodor Petrov:
>
> > 1. The project is Code::Blocks. I doubt it can be classified as large 200-300kloc.
> > 2. The style guide is here http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Coding_style